# Passing extra compilation flags to debug build in bitbake recipe

Tags: debugging, cmake, compilation, yocto, bitbake

As Bitbake builds -dev and -debug for recipes is it possible for defining compilation definitions specific to debug build for a particular recipe. Lets say I have some source code under DEBUG_INFO  for some recipe i.e.,

```
#ifdef DEBUG_INFO

........... do something

#endif /* DEBUG_INFO */
```

and uses cmake in bitbake environment.

I want this flag be enabled for the debug binaries generated in the .debug folder. Is this possible?
If I use `EXTRA_OECMAKE = "-DDEBUG_INFO"` it gets enabled to both dev and debug builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. All packages of a recipe are built in one go, they're just the same files but split somehow.

The only difference is with "special flavors" of a recipe (native, nativesdk, target, multilib, toolchain-specific recipes, etc...), in that case, you can have different flags but still, all the packages resulting from the build of this "flavor" will be built with the same flag.

Comment: So, the debug build .debug is a release build but debug symbols retained?
Effectively can we assume that .debug is a release build but with some extra -g enabled ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build another variant of a package where a certain CMake flag is set in the compilation, you can create a variant of the recipe. If the main recipe is named `my-app_git.bb` you can create another recipe file named `my-app-tweak_git.bb` and a common base, `my-app.inc`. In the bb files, include the inc file:

```
require my-app.inc
```

Move most of what's now in `my-app_git.bb` to `my_app.inc`, e.g. `SRC_URI`, but define different contents for `EXTRA_OECMAKE` in the .bb files.

Now you will have to decide which one of *my-app* and *my-app-tweak* goes into the image by specifying either `my-app` or `my-app-tweak` in an `IMAGE_INSTALL` definition.

This is not exactly what you asked for, but as has been stated by qschulz, you cannot change the contents of the -dev and -dbg sub-packages.

Also note that *dbg* and *dev* can be considered reserved words for variants of the package name, so if you want to use something other than *tweak*, as in my example, you cannot use any of them.